# Cannot open include file: 'pnglibconf.h':No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, compiler-errors, cmake, libpng

I'm trying to build `libpng` in MS Visual studio 2015 community edition but when i built it, i got this error (i used cmake to compile [libpng](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/?source=typ_redirect) along with compiled [zlib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/zlib/1.2.8/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz/download?use_mirror=excellmedia&download=) to produce libpng's soln file `ALL_BUILD.vcxproj` )

> Cannot open include file: 'pnglibconf.h':No such file or directory

I think this a system specific error,when i try to build this on other system  it works fine(because pnglibconfig.h was present with MS VS soln folder).
 Is there any prerequisites that is missing?
 **Update:** I tried building libpng in both debug & release mode, both are showing the same error. Zlib builds fine.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using "configure", you may need to copy pnglibconf.h.prebuilt from the scripts directory to pnglibconf.h in your working directory.  See Section III of the INSTALL file in your libpng source directory.

Comment: I generated Visual studio solution file using cmake gui(configure,generated).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the folder where the png lib headers are to your include list in the VS project settings

Comment: Include folder appears after building(INSTALL project) png library.